# Form with dnyamic name won't submit data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

In the application, a user can register as an initial user of a subsequent user. When the user clicks yes or no to `Firm already registered?`, if yes, the script changes the form name and id to `subUserForm` and if they select no, `initialUserForm`, like so:

```
<span>Firm already registered?</span>
<label>Yes<input type="radio" name="typeRegister" id="subRegister"></label>
<label>No<inputtype="radio" name="typeRegister" id="initalRegister"></label>
```

And my submit button

```
<button class="btn btn--reg bg-phase-green pill-radius txt-white font-body font-weight-medium" type="submit" id="register" disabled>Register</button>
```

---

```
('#subRegister').change(function(){
   if(this.checked) {
     $('#registerForm').attr('name', 'subUserForm').attr('id', 'subUserForm');
   } else {
     $('#registerForm').attr('name', 'initialUserForm').attr('id', 'initialUserForm');
   }
})

$('#initalRegister').change(function(){
  if(this.checked) {
    $('#registerForm').attr('name', 'initialUserForm').attr('id', 'initialUserForm');
    } else {
      $('#registerForm').attr('name', 'subUserForm').attr('id', 'subUserForm');
    }
})
```

The reason is, depending on the option they select, it changes the request made.
I've checked that the name and id are being updated, and they are, but when I click submit, nothing happens. Nothing I logged, no request is made etc.

```
$('#initialUserForm').submit(function(e){
    console.log('initial');
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataString = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($('#initialUserForm').serializeArray()));
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/p3sweb/register/rest-user/',
        data: dataString,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error:function(errResponse) {
            console.log('fail')
        }
    })
})

$('#subUserForm').submit(function(e){
    console.log('sub');
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataString = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($('#subUserForm').serializeArray()));
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/p3sweb/register/rest-subsequent-user-step2/',
        data: dataString,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error:function(errResponse) {
            console.log('fail')
        }
    })
})
```

***Question***

Is there an issue with dynamically changing the name of a form, or am I missing something really simple to why the form data isn't being submitted?

Comment: Use `$(document).on('submit', '#initialUserForm', function(e){`

Comment: That worked. Can I ask two things? Why doesn't the `submit()` method work? And secondly, is this really a duplicate to the one you have tagged?